# JSP absolute paths

Tags: jsp, intellij-idea

Could someone explain why absolute paths not recommended to use in JSP (e.g., IntelliJ IDEA show me a warning)?
[image]

Comment: Because IntelliJ is smart enough to realize that you should always use a path that's relative to the root of your web context.

Comment: So there is no strict rule to use only relative or context-based paths?

Comment: There are no rules, my friend.  Write it any way you want and live with the consequences.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Consider the following code in your JSP:

```
<script src="/path/to/script.js" />
```

And you deploy your application on `www.example.com` in servlet context `myContext`, your script will be looked up by the browser in

```
www.example.com/path/to/script.js
```

However, the browser will not find the script. The URL where it can actually be found containts the servlet context as well as part of the URL:

```
www.example.com/myContext/path/to/script.js
```

So you should change the URL in your JSP to:

```
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/path/to/script.js" />
```

Then the context path is also available in the URL and everything will work fine.

Comment: This didn't work at all for me. It just rendered files with the path looking something like: localhost:8080/profile/$%7BpageContext.request.context%7D/css/profile/

Comment: @MattPowell seems like your expression `${...}` did not get evaluated right. Some frameworks require to use `#{...}` instead, did you try that?

Comment: @w4rumy Thanks. It turns out I was using an outdated version of JSP. Once I updated to the latest version, the syntax worked correctly.

Comment: Probably we can just write `path/to/script.js` without any prepending slash or context variable, am I right?

Comment: @ieXcept Of course you can use relative paths, too, but you have to take into account in which directories your source files are.