# Getting Requested resource not found-404 error, for requestmapping and href's in Spring tool suite

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have searched through many similar questions, but unfortunately didnt get the solution.

*index.jsp:*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Welcome</title>
    </head> 
    <body>
    <form action="login">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Lets get Started">
    </form> 
    </body>
</html>
```

*MyController:*

```
package com.productivity.Controllers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class LoginController{
    @RequestMapping(value="/login")
    public String Login(){
        return "login";
    }
}
```

So when ever i click on submit in index.jsp,it should map(/login) controller and
shd be proceeding login.jsp. 
But it is showing, 
**HTTP Status 404 - /ProductivityTemple/login
type Status report
message /ProductivityTemple/login
description The requested resource is not available.**

Everything is set ryt,
*mvc-config.xml :*

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
     <context:annotation-config/>
       <context:component-scan
            base-package="com.productivity.Controllers"/> 

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <!-- Example: a logical view name of 'showMessage' is mapped to '/WEB-INF/jsp/showMessage.jsp' -->
            <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/"/>
            <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>
```

*application-config.xml:*

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.productivity"/>
```

*web.xml:*

```
 <context-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath:spring/application-config.xml</param-value>
        </context-param>

        <listener>
            <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
        </listener>


        <!--
            - Servlet that dispatches request to registered handlers (Controller implementations).
        -->
        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
                <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-config.xml</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>

        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
```

Deployment assembly also has all folders mapped correctly.

I tried by keeping href of login.jsp directly in index.jsp ,still i got same error.

```
<a href="login.jsp">Login</a>
```

**HTTP Status 404 - /ProductivityTemple/login.jsp
type Status report
message /ProductivityTemple/login.jsp
description The requested resource is not available.**

I think it is some settings in STS , please help me in getting the solution. Struck with this problem from 4 days.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `<a href="/login">Login</a>`

Answer (score 0):

From your error message HTTP Status 404 you deployed your project under `/ProductivityTemple/login.jsp` path.

Try use:

`<form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/login">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login">
</form>`

in index.jsp

Read also [JSP Absolute paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15759549/jsp-absolute-paths)

It helps me

And check if you have login.jsp file the same location as your index.jsp