# Intellij IDEA - Defining individual context roots for multiple modules in tomcat

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea, module

Tomcat and/or Intellij IDEA is making me crazy...

In a few words, I have one project with 2 modules, them both has jsp and/or html files using absolute path for images, scripts, etc...

[Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPvEh.jpg)

When I deploy the first with slash ("/"), I can see my images, my scripts are loaded perfectly, however, the module two, deployed as ("/module2") doesn't load images, scripts and nothing with the absolute path because the context root is the server, not the artifact...

[Error because the module context isn't inserted in the absolute path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dcz1a.jpg)

Here is the IntelliJ IDE project, it`s a small one and reflects the behavior that I explainned.

[Project with 2 modules](https://ufile.io/wtd9e)

Can someone help me on this?

Best regards,
Alex Florindo

Comment: Please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: CrazyCoder, I edited my post inserting the project on it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did my answer help?

Comment: Yeap CrazyCoder, my problem was more complex of this simple example. In a few words, the solution is a SPA and after the login, I have a ajax requisition that loads the html page code and insert it in the page and using the HTML5 historyAPI I was changing the URL in the browser to the main page, and IT WAS my problem, because in some browsers (firefox in android and chrome in IOS) was generating a wrong URL(repeating part of the address) with the relative path that I was using... My alternative in that moment was change ALL paths of the html using the absolute one. It's why my questions...

Comment: To finish, the solution was: I passed all the URL (using my context + the relative address of the main page) and that error (part of the URL repeated) was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15760171/104891).

IntelliJ IDEA has a quick fix for this:

[image: fix1]

[image: fix2]

After Alt+Enter, Enter, you will get the code changed to:

```
<img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/imgs/user_bg1.png">
```

You can run this inspection across the whole project and apply the quick fixes in batch for all the affected code parts.

Comment: CrazyCoder, thanks again! I understood your answer. Tell another thing, is it possible to do the same in a HTML5? (html file)?

Comment: Use the relative paths instead of the absolute paths starting with `/`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48417861/104891.